# Не получается отправить дробное число

Tags: python, telebot

Не получается отправить боту дробное число.
Код:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'calculate':
            bot.edit_message_text(text_1, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, value_1)



    def value_1(message):
        global val_1, val_2
        val_1 = int(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text_2)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, value_2)

    def value_2(message):
        global val_1, val_2
        val_2 = int(message.text)

        number_1 = val_1
        number_2 = val_2

        profit = (number_2 - number_1)
        percent = (number_1 / 100)
        total = '{:.2f}'.format(profit / percent)

        total_val_1 = '{:.1f}'.format(val_1)
        total_val_2 = '{:.1f}'.format(val_2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' Результат расчета\n\nСумма покупки:  {total_val_1}\nСумма продажи:  {total_val_2}\n\nПроцент спреда равен:  {total} %')
```

Когда я отправляю числа, они записываются в переменные val, но когда я отправляю дробное число, то бот зависает.

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Телепатов тут нет. Объясняйте что это значит конкретно.

Comment: Когда я отправляю числа, они записываются в переменные val, но когда я отправляю дробное число, то бот зависает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ведь все равно числа к дроби приводите, зачем int(message.text)?

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

val_1 = 0
val_2 = 0
text_1 = 'введите первое число'
text_2 = 'введите второе число'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка', callback_data='calculate'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'calculate')
def callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    bot.edit_message_text(text_1, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, value_1)


def value_1(message: types.Message):
    global val_1
    val_1 = float(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text_2)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, value_2)


def value_2(message: types.Message):
    global val_1, val_2
    val_2 = float(message.text)

    number_1 = val_1
    number_2 = val_2

    profit = (number_2 - number_1)
    percent = (number_1 / 100)
    total = '{:.2f}'.format(profit / percent)

    total_val_1 = '{:.1f}'.format(val_1)
    total_val_2 = '{:.1f}'.format(val_2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f' Результат расчета\n\n'
                     f'Сумма покупки:  {total_val_1}\n'
                     f'Сумма продажи:  {total_val_2}\n\n'
                     f'Процент спреда равен:  {total} %')


bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]